# Mongoose: updating new values only if not null

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object, mongoose

I already got another solution but cannot understand why mine doesn't work.

I tried to use $set: here but it didn't help. objForUpdate do return "name, lastname" when i print. If i replace {objForUpdate} with {name, lastname} - update works. But I cannot pass the parameters in variable.

```
//Route to UPDATE user
    async updateUser(req, res) {
        let { _id, type, name, lastname } = req.body;
        try {
             let objForUpdate = "";
             for (var key in req.body) {
                 if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(key) && req.body.key !== null && req.body[key] !== "" && key !== '_id') {
                     console.log("this is key: " + key + ", and this is value req.body[key]: " + req.body[key]);
                     objForUpdate += key + ", ";
                 }
            }
            objForUpdate = objForUpdate.slice(0, -2); 
            const updated = await Users.updateOne({ _id }, {objForUpdate});
            res.send({ updated });
        } catch (error) {
            res.send({ error });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would debug the code, you'll get it.

Lets say the `req.body` looks like `{ name: "foo", lastname: "bar" type: "2", _id: 1}` and by the end of the for-loop and the slice op the `objForUpdate` would be `"name, lastname, type"` which is a **string**.

Now when you pass this string to the updateOne op, this part **`{objForUpdate}`** will get converted to **`{ objForUpdate: "name, lastname, type" }`** (a conversion of identifier as key and its defined value as the value of that key).

And that update object is incorrect even with `$set` operator.

---

If i replace {objForUpdate} with {name, lastname} - update works. Why?

Because in this case with [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) you unpacked the object as independent variables (name, lastname ...) with values. In this case the **`{objForUpdate}`** when passed would become **`{"name":"foo", "lastname":"bar", "type":"2"}`** which is correct as update object.